# Batch script in order to search words in files and replace them

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently trying to do a script in order to find a sentence in files and replace this line by another one. 
I have already made this :

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=@Interceptors({ RuntimeExceptionInterceptor.class })"
set "replace=@Interceptors({ RuntimeExceptionInterceptor.class, ReportInterceptor.class })"

set "textFile=test2.txt"

for /f %%i %%f in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i %%f"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

But it doesn't work, this script is unable to replace my first line by the one that I want, can you help me please :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some erros in your code:

- the for has only one expressed variable, via `"tokens="` you can define more when splitting input at the chars listed with `"delims="` See `help for`
- you can't write to the same while still reading it.
- the closing parenthesis in your search and replace strings causes the for loop to break - you need to escape them with a `^`.

---

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions Disabledelayedexpansion

:: take care the closing parenthesis has to be escaped with a caret 
set "search=@Interceptors({ RuntimeExceptionInterceptor.class }^)"
set "replace=@Interceptors({ RuntimeExceptionInterceptor.class, ReportInterceptor.class }^)"

set "textFile=test2.txt"
set "text_new=test2.new"

( for /f "Delims=" %%i in (
    'type "%textFile%"  '
  ) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    Call echo:%%line:%search%=%replace%%%
  )
)  > "%text_new%"
type "%text_new%"
```

Replacing the old file with the new one is left for you.

Answer (score 1):

why not use the `sed` command with the `-i` flag? this sounds like what the tool is made for

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to fix the problem using a different approach instead of a batch file. Presumably, you are developing using a Java IDE. Use its global replace facility; e.g. in IntelliJ IDEA, use the option "Replace in path...".